# How to create groups for twitter bootstrap typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, bootstrap-typeahead, optgroup

I'm not very familiar with customizing twitter bootstrap, could any one please explain how to add groups to typeahead in bootstrap, similar to the optgroup tag in html. I found this plugin that does what I want but I want to customize it more and understand how it was done https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead.

Comment: Hey there @k_programmer, no... not yet :(.